# How To Enable Spinner as Long as EditText field is not empty

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-spinner

I have an EditText and a Spinner. Initially the Spinner is Disabled, I want it to get enabled whenever there is some text in the EditText, For Example if i type something into the EditText Field it should get enabled and as i erase the text till there is nothing else the Spinner should go back to disabled, Any Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `TextWatcher` on the `EditText` field and check the contents of the `CharSequence` against `""`. If they're equal, disable the `Spinner`, otherwise enable it.

```
private Spinner mySpinner; // Of course, this has to be defined somewhere

// ...

final EditText editBox = (EditText) findViewById(<your EditText field>);
editBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // Nothing
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // Nothing
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (s.toString().equals("")) {
            mySpinner.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            mySpinner.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
});
```

You may also want to check `mySpinner.isEnabled()` before calling `setEnabled(...)` on it.

Answer (score 0):

use addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher watcher) for the EditText widget and check if the widget getText() is not empty string then enable the spinner.